# Search and delete array element in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like:

```
A = ['a', 'del', 'b', 'del', 'c']
```

how can i remove the elements del such that the result is,

```
B = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I tried the pop and indexOf method but was unable

Comment: If you say that you tried something and it did not work, then you should show what you have tried and why a question like "[Remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325)" did not help you. (I know that this question is about removing multiple elements, whether my referenced one is only about removing one, but the answers target both). If you show your attempt then it would be also possible to tell you what why your did try not work.

Comment: Howcome, is this question not duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop to remove an element in array with multiple occurrences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733207/loop-to-remove-an-element-in-array-with-multiple-occurrences)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** for filtering elements from an array

```js
var A = ['a', 'del', 'b', 'del', 'c'];

var B = A.filter(function(v) {
  return v != 'del';
});
 
console.log(B);
```

---

For older browser check [polyfill option of filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill).

---

In case if you want to remove element from existing array then use **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** with a for loop

```js
var A = ['a', 'del', 'b', 'del', 'c'];

for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  if (A[i] == 'del') {
    A.splice(i, 1); // remove the eleemnt from array
    i--; //  decrement i since one one eleemnt removed from the array
  }
}

console.log(A);
```

Comment: `filter` creates a NEW array, vs `splice` which modifies the existing array.  The difference can be crucial.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher :  as per the question , I think he needs to create a new array B ,  `B = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: @ubuntuser : glad to help :)